# Remove third-party Excel Add-ins

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I added some third-party add-ins to MS Excel 2010 and want to remove them now.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

```
File => Options => Add-ins => Manage: COM Add-ins => Go
```

You'll be able to add new add-ins and disable/enable/remove any installed third party add-ins here.

Comment: I didn't change it to `COM Add-ins` and they appeared in the `Add-ins` list... THANKS!

Comment: @neildeadman: Anytime. :)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

1. Go to the original location where the addin is loaded from and rename the file
2. `File => Options => Add-ins => Manage: COM Add-ins => Go` and click on the addin again. Click yes to remove the addin permanently from Excel's memory.

You should do what @Roney-Michael suggested, if you just want to disable the excel addin. However, that doesn't remove the add-in completely from excel.

You will notice, that after you restart excel and go to

`File => Options => Add-ins => Manage: COM Add-ins => Go`, the excel addin is still there.

There are a lot of articles online which talk about editing the registry values to permanently delete a add-in from Excel from the: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/registry-keys.htm

However, that didn't work either.

Excel doesn't copy your addin into a special folder. Rather, when you double -click on a `.xla/.xlam` file to load a `addin`, it creates a `link` in excel to point to the `.xla/.xlam` file in the same folder. So what worked well, is to rename the actual `.xlam/.xla` file located in which ever folder its located in (for me it was in `C:\runnum\addin.xlam`, the same directory from which I originally loaded the addin.)

Then go back to `File => Options => Add-ins => Manage: COM Add-ins => Go`, and double click the same addin. It will mention that the addin is missing and ask whether you want to delete the addin from excel. If you do, it will permanently delete that `addin` from Excel's memory.